# How do I export my model with some light (in .gltf)?

Tags: export, light, lighting, gltf

I'm working on a model and I'm trying to export it in .gltf format.

In blender, I put a light to brighten the model, but when I export it, the lighting goes away.

I'm quite new to blender and I've tried some things, such as using a tool called ssgi but with no success.

What should I do to have the lighting in the export?

[image: With lights]

The model with the light when I'm working in blender.

[image: Without lights]

The same model but with no lights when I preview it.

Answer (score 7):

There's an "Include: Punctual Lights" option in the exporter that will include point, spot, and directional lights in your exports. However, note that (by default) Blender also displays "Scene World" lighting, and you can't just export that. You'd typically need to enable it in whatever viewer or 3D engine you are using to view the model, and that depends on the engine. A typical term for this would be "IBL" or "environment maps" in some engines. Metallic materials, in particular, require this type of lighting to look correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Don. I tried what you said with the export option, and just to test it, I imported it in a new blender project but there was no lighting. Also, forgot to mention I'm using the 2.83 version.

Comment: You may want to file a bug on https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO then. Another option would be to run `gltf-transform inspect model.glb` (with https://gltf-transform.donmccurdy.com/cli.html) and see if the `KHR_lights_punctual` extension is listed at the top. If so, the file contains lights and your engine may not be importing them. If not, they aren't being exported.